# Creating a Script for filtering by criteria in sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm very new to coding and would appreciate any support with what is probably a simple script.

I want to create a script that triggers daily, that filters by criteria on a few different columns.

I have searched the web and can only find help with sorting. I can't seem to find answers when it comes to filtering by criteria.

I want to filter Column D (Status) to any cells that do not have the value 'Closed' and want to also filter column T (Scope) to have only had the value 'Strategic'

Then sort this range by 1st column. (Which I believe I have achieved below)
I then want to run a trigger on this daily which I can set up after.

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Data Studio")

  var range = ss.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow()-1, ss.getLastColumn())

range.sort([{column: 1, descending: false}]);}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not so simple. You need to use filter and filterBuilder, which are not the most intuitive. Here's the basic code to get you started. Modify this for your needs.

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Data Studio");

  var range = ss.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow()-1, ss.getLastColumn());

  // Get the existing filter, else create one for this range. May need to just
  // remove all filters first in case they conflict.
  var filter = range.getFilter() || range.createFilter();

  var column_Status = 4; // column D
  var filterCriteria_Status = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
    .whenTextDoesNotContain('Closed')
    .build();

  var column_Scope = 20; // column T
  var filterCriteria_Scope = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
    .whenTextContains('Strategic')
    .build();

  var column_to_sort = 1;
  filter.setColumnFilterCriteria(column_Status, filterCriteria_Status)
    .setColumnFilterCriteria(column_Scope, filterCriteria_Scope)
    .sort(column_to_sort, true);
}
```

Setting a daily trigger is pretty straightforward from menu: Edit > Current project's triggers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that worked for me (as I personally could not make the solution shown in the accepted answer to work):

```
function onEdit(e){

  var ss = e.source.getActiveSheet()  
  var ra = e.range
  var erow = e.range.getRow() 
  var ecolumn = e.range.getColumn()

// name of the sheet + coordinates of the searchbox (here is A1)
  
  if (erow == 1 && ecolumn == 1 && ss.getName()=="Sheet1" ){
    var val = ra.getValue()
    var rang = ss.getDataRange();
    var filterCriteria = SpreadsheetApp
    .newFilterCriteria()
    .whenTextContains(val) 
    .build();
    var filter = rang.getFilter() || rang.createFilter();
    filter.setColumnFilterCriteria(3, filterCriteria); // column to search = 3
  }
  
}
```

Cheers,
Jean